# Missing c wire for new thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Tying to install new smart thermostat but no c wire available. Was going to use g wire in c terminal but noticed the the g wire( old thermostat) is green and when I checked furnace,that green wire is spliced to another green wire that maybe connected to a/c or vanee air exchanger. G terminal on furnace has a black wire? Can I move black g wire to c terminal as suggested online ? See pictures [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l5o3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Wire colors are free choice, use the letter labels.

The G is usually for Fan only function

You have a C- marked on the right.

R is 24 Volt.

W- is heating

Y- is cooling

Without knowing more about your HVAC, no better answer is possible.

For example you have 2 wires in R (someone else (other then thermostat) gets 24 volt.

You also have 2 wires in Y, Someone else gets a command to run when cooling is on?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the G wire as a C wire, but we will need more information to guide you through wiring up a new thermostat. Give us a zoomed out picture of the furnace board showing where all the wires go (wire nuts, other equipment, etc) as well as the equipment involved. Also provide a picture of the wiring at the thermostat.

Since your color scheme appears antiquated and you already mentioned moving the G wire, is your thermostat wire only 4-conductor? And is there a possibility of running a new thermostat wire? I ask because it simplifies things greatly if you can run 5 or 7 conductor wire to the new thermostat.